# How to implement a "hasChildren" SELECT statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, select

Let's say I have the following table:

```
ID | parentID | MoreStuff
1  | -1       |  ...
2  |  1       |  ...
3  |  1       |  ...
4  |  2       |  ...
5  |  1       |  ...
```

How can I generate an SQL SELECT statement to find out if a specific row has children? In other words, I want to know if ID 1 has children, which in this case it has 3.

I'm not sure how to create the SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, hasChildren FROM myTable;
```

What would be replaced for hasChildren in the above SQL SELECT statement?

Comment: What database?  Oracle has LEAD & LAG functions you could use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No group version:

```
SELECT MyTable.Id, CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT TOP 1 1  --you can actually select anything you want here
     FROM MyTable MyTableCheck 
     WHERE MyTableCheck.ParentId = MyTable.Id
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasRows
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: +1 for exists, beat me to it! :)  Op: This is this most efficient on here so far, as exists returns as soon as it knows if a child rows exists, meaning it doesn't have to count all of the children.  If all you care about is the existence of children this is the way to do it.

Comment: Minor point, but you could have written that a little more elegantly as WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM MyTable...)

Comment: The Top 1 is not needed, see my above comment.  Exists stops at the first match anyways.  Selecting null, 1, or * has no real effect, all exists cares about is that something came back.  The optimizer won't actually fetch the data.

Answer (score 12):

Join the table on itself to find if it has children:

```
SELECT 
    parent.id as ID
,   case when count(child.id) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as hasChildren 
FROM       myTable parent
LEFT JOIN  myTable child
ON         child.parentID = parent.ID
GROUP BY   parent.id
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know already know the parent ID, then the query is simple -- just select the number of rows with that parent ID.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable where parentID = 1;
```

Comment: +1 for being the only query that actually answers if "a specific row has children"

Comment: Your query is to find if a specific row has children. But how do I get a list of all rows with an extra column created dynamically called hasChildren?

Comment: To get a list of all rows with an extra column see Alex or Andomar's answers. However, the question explicitly asks for a query "to find out if *a specific row* has children", and this is what Kaleb's answer does.

Answer (score 2):

There are very valid answers to your question which will work. However, I would consider the performance of such a query if your dataset is very large.

If your going to use a Group By or Sub Query to get the data, then make sure both the ID and Parent columns have separate indexes.

To get even better performance, you should add a column called "haschildren" which could be a "bit" datatype. This column should then be updated from your application code when items are Inserted or Deleted. This would allow you to run the much quicker query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE haschildren IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above are fine, but you shouldn't add column like 'haschildren' unless you really have a performance problem (see the post by GateKiller). Such a column denormalizes the database, i.e. the same piece of information will be stored in 2 places, which makes it more likely for your data to become inconsistent. You will have to maintain this column whenever you insert a new child, delete an existing one or update the parent of a child.

Comment: Since he's asking for a query to indicate if a child exists or not, this is not denormalizing anything.  If he were to update the base table, then it would, but I don't get the feeling that that is what he means.

Comment: +1 - these are valid concerns, whether it's technically denormalisation or not.

Comment: I was referring to the post by GateKiller, and what he is suggests is denormailization.

Comment: @FelixM: Then your answer should have been a comment to GateKiller's answer, and not a separate answer in itself. That's the way SO works - comments are comments to answers and answers are answers to the original question. Yours answered nothing related to the original question.